# Segmentation fault when using cmpq operand in x86

Tags: recursion, assembly, segmentation-fault, x86-64

So I'm trying to find some user input from a Query String in asm x86. The 2 inputs are "9" and "6" in the string "m1=9&m2=6".

I keep getting a segmentation fault at line 14. I don't seem to know why, I even tried debugging, but I can't seem to find the problem while trying to move things around.

```
    .section .rodata
test: 
    .string "m1=9&m2=6"
    .text
    .globl   main
    .type    main, @function
main:
    pushq   %rbp
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
    movq    $test,%rbx
    movq    %rbx,%rax
while3:
   cmpq     $'=',(%rax)          
   incq     %rax          
   jne while3   
innerwhile1:
    cmpq    $'&',(%rax)
    incq    %rax
    jne innerwhile1
    movq    %rax,%r10
while4:
    cmpq     $'=',(%rbx)          
    incq     %rax
    jne while4
innerwhile4:
    cmpq    $'\n',(%rax)
    incq    %rax
    jne innerwhile1
    movq    %rax,%r11
    ret
```

I'm sorry if this is a basic question, I am very new to asm.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: In the while4 loop, rax is being incremented, but rbx is being used for the comparison.

Answer (score 3):

`incq %rax` sets the flags, so `jne while3` loops based on the result of the inc instead of the result of the compare. This is a problem in the other loops as well.

Or better, `inc` first then `cmpb $imm8, -1(%rax)`, allowing macro-fusion of the cmp/jcc into a single compare-and-branch uop.

Also, `cmpq $'\n'` only sets ZF if an entire QWORD has the value `0x000000000000000a`.  Use `cmpb` to for operand-size = byte.

Comment: One possible solution for this is to use `lea 1(%rax), %rax` which doesn't change the flags.

Comment: Or better, inc first then `cmpb $imm8, -1(%rax)`, allowing macro-fusion of the cmp/jcc

Comment: I knew you would come up with a better suggestion, which is why I put mine in a comment instead of in the answer. Feel free to add it to the answer if you like.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like lines after label `innerwhile4` check for `\n` but that symbol is not present in the value `.string "m1=9&m2=6"` therefore loop enumerates memory space and eventually hits the end of the memory allocated to a process which leads to segmentation fault.

Comment: Even before that, the code in `while3` does `cmpq`, `incq`, `jne`.  While cmpq sets the zf (which is what jne checks), so does incq.

Comment: More importantly, `cmpq $'\n'` only sets ZF if an entire QWORD has the value `0x000000000000000a`.  I think the OP wants `cmpb` (operand-size = byte).